# Custom ImageView shape drawable in xml like this one

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable

I want to create an ImageView like this one. I know it's a combination of a rectangle and a triangle shape, but I really don't know how to implement it.

[image]

Is it possible in XML?. Does layer-list seem to help in this case?. I would like to have some example drawable xml codes. [The example Image belongs to someone from Dribbble.]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible in XML?

yes, I think you can achieve this by manipulating corner tag attributes

(for example):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<corners 
android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
/>
</shape>
```

here we specified  `bottomRightRadius` to be 0 and topLeftRadius to be 15 which will effect one corner and that would results irregular shape similar to the one that you have requested.
try to play around with those attributes to achieve what you are asking for.

hope this will help.

Comment: It doesn't help. Radius gives circular mask to the image, rather than the desired one.

Comment: what about   strokes! <stroke/>

Comment: Doesn't strokes give border to the view?

Comment: yes some how it can be used like that but try to manipulate its attribute to get what you need. i'll try to implement what you need as soon as i get free and will edit the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on the same. Can't we add two shapes together. Like a rectangle and a right angled triangle in a layer list?

Comment: yes you can, try to add those as items into a layer list and tell me what you get, hope it will work out for you.